# Pandas - ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe indexed by datetime.

```
index

2021-05-09 23:06:14.666
2021-05-09 23:06:14.786
2021-05-09 23:06:14.969
2021-05-09 23:06:15.022
2021-05-09 23:06:15.102
```

I'm trying to add 2000 milliseconds to the index datetime and create a new column.

```
df["new_time"] = df.index[df.index.get_indexer([df.index + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=2000)], method='nearest')[0]]
```

But i'm getting the following error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can someone tell me how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the following command, no need to over complicate it

```py
df["new_time"] =  df.index + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=2000)
```

Second option use relativedelta:

```py
import dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta as rd 
df["new_time"] =  df.index + rd(microseconds=2000)
```

Comment: Thanks. But this would give me values that are not in the index. Hence, I'm using the nearest method.

Comment: @John updated with a secondary answer. Shouldn't be the case that it doesn't work
Are you trying to round it up?

Comment: Thanks again. But you are still missing my point. The index is not uniform. Look at the milliseconds part. They end with like this. `666, 786, 969, 022, 102`. When you add 2000 milliseconds to `2021-05-09 23:06:14.666`, then the value would look like `2021-05-09 23:06:16.666`. The `new_time` column will be used to query data like this. `df.loc[new_time:]`. If `2021-05-09 23:06:16.666` not exists, then there will be errors. `df.index[df.index.get_indexer([df.index + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=2000)], method='nearest')[0]]` returns the nearest index.

Comment: @John that's not an initial question, provide an example output, are you trying to filtrate the data?

Comment: No, I need only the index + 2000 milliseconds in my new column. But I'll be doing filtering at a later time in a different function. What I tried to explain in my last comment is that, I need the `new_time` column to be a valid index. Not just +2000 milliseconds to the current index.

Comment: @John please provide an example output

Comment: Hi Akmal, the output will be way too long to print here. This is how I'm doing a loop. `for i, row in df.iterrows():
    idx = df.index[df.index.get_indexer([i + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=2000)], method='nearest')[0]]`. So I think we need to use df.apply.